# Adjacent multiple elements removing in Python sequences

Tags: python, sequence

I have a sequence like `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]` and I need a function to remove repeated adjacent sequence pairs, keeping the first one, and return `[0, 1, 0]`. These are some results I expect.

```
>>> remove_repeated_pairs([0, 1])
[0, 1]
>>> remove_repeated_pairs([0, 1, 0])
[0, 1, 0]
>>> remove_repeated_pairs([0, 1, 0, 1])
[0, 1]
>>> remove_repeated_pairs([0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
[0, 1, 0]
>>> remove_repeated_pairs([2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
[2, 0, 1, 0]
>>> remove_repeated_pairs([1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
[1, 2, 0, 1, 0]
```

first edition:

I tried this code:

```
def remove_repeated_pairs(seq):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(seq), 2):
        if len(result) >= 2:
            last_seq = result[-2:]
        else:
            last_seq = None
        pair = seq[i:i + 2]
        if pair != last_seq:
            result.extend(pair)
    return result
```

But it doesn't works with this:

```
>>> remove_repeated_pairs([1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0])
[1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0]
```

The right answer should be `[1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0]`

Comment: Hello, @robert. I updated my question with I tried.

Comment: And what is the right answer for that example you added? `[1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0]`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I need to keep the first ocurrence of `[0, 1]` and remove the following. Thus, `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]` should produce `[0, 1, 0]`.

Comment: @agf, I updated with the right answer. The elements `[2, 1]` are repeated and adjacent.

Comment: Is this only required to remove two-element patterns? Or should it remove repeated patterns of any length? E.g., should the input `[2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1]` be shrunk to `[2, 0, 1]`?

Comment: @Blair, only two-element patterns will be considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the issue comes from the fact that you go over the elements of your list 2 by 2 (for i in range(0, len(seq), 2).
So if a repeated pair starts on an odd place, you won't detect it - as in the last example you give.

I would try something like:

```
def remove_repeated_pairs(l):
    i = 2;
    while i < len(l)-1:
            if l[i] == l[i-2] and l[i+1]==l[i-1]:
                l.pop(i);
                l.pop(i);
            else:
                i+=1;

    return l;
```

Regards,

Comment: note: `L.pop(i)` is an `O(N)` operation; it makes this algorithm `O(N**2)` though it doesn't matter for small lists.

Comment: Absolutely, your version is more efficient - thx for the feedback

Answer (score 3):

Here's version that works with an arbitrary iterable, not just sequences:

```
def remove_repeated_pairs(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    a = next(it) # always yield the first pair
    yield a
    b = next(it)
    yield b

    c = next(it)
    for d in it:
        if a != c or b != d:
            yield c
            a, b, c = b, c, d # shift by one item
        else: # repeated pair, skip it
            a, b, c = c, d, next(it)
    yield c
```

#### Example

```
>>> list(remove_repeated_pairs([1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0]))
[1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more concise version:

```
def remove_repeated_pairs(seq):
    pairs = zip([-1] + seq,seq)[1:]
    l = [index for (index,pair) in enumerate(pairs) if (index > 1) and
                (pair == pairs[index-2])]
    return [seq[x] for x in range(len(seq)) if x not in l and x+1 not in l ]

print remove_repeated_pairs([1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 0])
#OUTPUT: [1, 3, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0]

print remove_repeated_pairs([1, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 3])
#OUTPUT: [1, 2, 4, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check pairs starting at odd indices as well, i.e. pairs seq[1:2] equals seq[3:4] as well as even ones, i.e. seq[0:1] equals seq[2:3]

Answer (score 0):

You need to move forward one by one instead of two by two

```
def remove_repeated_pairs(l):
     if(len(l) < 4):
         return l
     result = l[:2]
     i = 2
     while i < (len(l)-1):
         if l[i] == result[-2] and l[i+1] == result[-1]:
             i += 2
         else:
             result.append(l[i])
             i += 1
     result += l[i:]
     return result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove_repeated_pairs(seq):
    ret = [seq[0]]
    s = None
    i = 1
    while i < len(seq)-1:
        pair = (seq[i], seq[i+1])
        if pair != s:
            s = (seq[i-1], seq[i])
            ret.append(seq[i])
        else:
            i+=1
        i+=1
    if i == len(seq)-1:
        ret.append(seq[i])
    return ret
```